# Publicação de Projeto ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Bom dia senhores, trabalho com desenvolvimento de sistemas, mas até então nunca precisei fazer uma publicação em internet de uma aplicação minha, pois sempre trabalhei com projetos prontos, qual a melhor forma e onde fazer um publicação do meu projeto onde eu possa acessar ele pelo www.meusite.com.br? Poderiam me detalhar?

Comment: Depende muito dos recursos e permissões disponíveis na hospedagem e a versão do asp.net que está utilizando.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, gostaria apenas de publicas em uma hospedagem gratuita apenas para testes da aplicação, pois por exemplo, gostaria de testar meu app no celular, por isso o publish do meu projeto asp.net mvc

Comment: recomendo que você primeiro faça uma pesquisa sobre o assunto, faça as suas tentativas e depois retorne aqui com algum problema específico... caso ocorra algum...

Comment: Mesmo dentro do asp.net existe muitas formas diferentes de fazer isso como publicação direta através do VS par ao Azure, através do GIT, através de um FTP, criando uma pasta local e copiando manualmente, etc. Depende, do projeto e do ambiente do servidor. Conforme comentado pelo pessoal é preciso que gere um problema mais específico para que possam ajuda-lo.  :)

Comment: Se é só pra testar, vc pode habilitar o IIS no seu computador, e acessar... Pode até criar um domínio dinâmico (no-ip, dyndns) e torná-lo público... Acho que é mais viável aprender a publicar no próprio computador, depois pública em uma hospedagem... E serviços gratuitos pra hospedar ASP.net acho difícil... Normalmente só demonstração

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que a principio você poderia usar o AZURE para publicar sua aplicação Web.
Crie uma conta gratuita no AZURE e crie sua aplicação web lá.
Após isso você pode fazer a publicação da sua aplicação Web já setando no publish do projeto para que seja hospedado na sua conta do azure.

Este link pode de ajudar a entender melhor:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Consegui realizar o que eu queria pelo Azure, criei uma conta grátis e realizei o publish diretamente para o azure! eles me liberam uma URL onde conecto minha aplicação, consegui perfeitamente realizar o teste em meu celular.

Comment: Que bom que tenha conseguido progredir com o seu objetivo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Bom primeiramente você tem que ter um provedor para hospedar seu projeto e que vai redirecionar para seu dominio "www.meusite.com.br".
Se você não optar o Azure e contratar qualquer outro provedor de hospedagem, a maneira mais fácil é você dar um "publish" da sua aplicação aspnet para um diretorio windows, ali ele vai colocar seus arquivos pronto para publicação.
Para publicar, você precisa ter um endereço de FTP que o seu provedor contratado irá fornecer, e com este acesso, através de um programa de FTP, basta conectar e enviar seus arquivos obtido pelo "Publish" para o diretório do seu provedor.
Resumidamente este é o caminho mais simples. Claro que se foi desenvolver para hospedar no azure, o caminho é diferente, segue no citado na resposta acima, mas o Visual Studio conecta automaticamente e publica sua aplicação lá, basta conectar na sua conta pelo Visual Studio, isso é bem simples, mas ao dar o publish indicar que será no Azure.
Claro que ao contratar a hospedagem, deve ser configurado para asp.net, e informar o framework que esta sua aplicação, então primeiro verifique o framework que seu provedor disponibiliza e de build da sua aplicação para este framework.